# Windows 7 System resume not working

Tags: windows-7, filesystem-corruption, system-recovery

I have a windows 7 desktop. Today when I tried to start it. A black screen appeared.
With option

1) continue with resume data 
2)delete restoration data and proceed to system boot menu

But the keyboard and mouse is not working

I tried myself with this methods 
1) removed the motherboard battery and put it again. And a screen appeared to bios setup. I tried all options. But when the PC rebooted. The same screen appeared

I have read in posts that it is because of corrupted
 hiberfil.sys file. 
Now my question is if I use my hard disk enclosure and use my current hard disk as an external hard disk on an another computer. And from there I delete the  hiberfil.sys file. 
1) will it delete all the files on my harddisk
And 
2) will I be able to boot my PC when I put it in previous pc

Comment: What type of keyboard/mouse? If wireless, try a wired one. If USB try a PS/2… basically go back 'one technology' & test again.

Comment: It is a wired USB mouse. I tried wireless USB mouse but didn't work. Should I use a wired ps/2 mouse?

Comment: Yes, some older BIOS only supported wired keyboards.